# tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model error: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'feature_columns'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to save my model in a .pb or .pbtxt format using tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, saved_model_dir)  as described in the following tutorial:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/data-science-on-gcp/blob/master/updates/cloudml/flights_model_tf2.ipynb

but I get the error:

**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'feature_columns'

Thank you in advance for your help. Code below:

```
#my code, the model trains without any problems:

training_history = model.fit(train_ds, 
                    validation_data=val_ds,
                    epochs=epochs, 
                    callbacks=[EarlyStopping(patience=patience), tensorboard_callback ])

now=str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(':','_').replace(' ','_').replace('.','_')

saved_model_dir="saved_models/"+now

tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, saved_model_dir)

#I get the following error:

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'feature_columns'
```